# Alternative to a very long switch-case statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I currently find myself in a situation, where I have to write a java programm that processes various methods in form of strings, after being scanned in. I currently handle it with a method, that has a pretty long switch-case statement that processes the method in form of a string. I am not sure whether this is a good approach or not, as I think it looks and probably behaves dirty, so I wanted to ask if there is a better solution for my problem.

Comment: Without any code it's impossible to answer. If the code works, you might want to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than SO

Comment: I find a well-indented and commented `switch` more transparent than a series of `if`s especially because `if`s tend to be much more abundant than `switch`es. But this might be a question which is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: You can find a solution here [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42125/refactoring-large-switch-statement). Code Review is the perfect site for this type of questions.

Comment: Sounds like a Code Review question to me, but make sure you bring your real working code. Both are requirements for CR.

Comment: In general you can replace an N-way switch with a base class with abstract method S having N derivations redefining S. Eliminating error-prone switches was one motivation for developing OO language features in the 80's.

Comment: Reflection may be an option.

Comment: @gene and how would one arrive at the class to instantiate given a string?

Comment: By using an enum lookup, for example.

Comment: @mick That can only work if the strings happen to be legal Java identifiers.

Comment: @Marko, it works with arbitrary strings if the lookup is implemented based on an enum property that corresponds to the values in the `switch`.

Comment: @mick That lookup is then the point of the answer, not the enum. Its implementation will be just as in Peter's answer, and his idea with lambdas beats the enum approach.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You wrap the strings with pojos.

Comment: @gene Is this supposed to be a response to my earlier question to you? I ask because I cannot make any sense of it.

Comment: @Marko, before this gets too off-topic, I'll conclude with a few remarks: Using `enum`s, you can write code that is much more self-documenting, OO, type-safe and legible than the `Map`-based variant. If the business problem is enumerable, you can pretty much always write the solution using an `enum` that implements a template method. I'd choose such a declarative way of binding actions to properties any time over the clunky and error-prone `Map`-based alternative; especially when Java 8 lambdas are available, because that makes the `enum` solution even more concise.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I think you fail te realize that your suggestion is as clunky and error-prone as the map-based approach. You cannot introduce type safety into a problem which starts out as a string read from an outside resource. The map-based approach is just more honest about it---and more lightweight. The only win you may have would be if there were _several_ operations being dispatched on the same string, then an enum instance would conveniently aggregate them all---although no better than a custom interface with several impls, backed by the map for dispatch.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Also, I forgot to mention that your enum approach would _still_ need the map to do efficient lookup of enum member. So the enum ends up as nothing but overhead. It forces you to cram everything into a single file, so it even adds inconvenience to the overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Map instead.

```
final Map<String, Consumer<String>> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
Consumer<String> defaultAction = ...
// add actions to the map
actionMap.put("case 1", s -> { doSomething() });
actionMap.put("case 2", s -> { doSomething() });
actionMap.put("case 3", s -> { doSomething() });

// instead of switch
String action = ...
actionMap.getOfDefault(action, defaultAction).apply(action);
```

With this construct you can lay out your "switch" any way you wish, dynamically and across many methods/class/libraries.